# Get data of last record with join in jpa

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring data jpa with hibernate implementation and postgres
I have two table

> table machine: id, name
>   table record:  id, machine_id, temp1, time_stamp

i search to get display last record (id, machine_id, name, temp1) for  every machine

this sql query seem to do the job

```
select r.*, d.*
from machine d
join record r on (d.id=r.machine_id)
left outer join record r2 on (d.id=tr2.machine_id and
(r.time_stamp<r2.time_stamp or r.time_stamp=r2.time_stamp and  r.id<r2.id)
)
where r2.id is null
```

But i search to do it in jpa

Comment: Please explicit what you want... This sql in JPQL?

Comment: it's clearly wrote the query is in sql... and i search to write it in jpql..

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have a bidirectional OneToOne relationship between Machine and Record entitys.

```
select machine
from Machine machine
inner join machine.record record
left join machine.record record2 

where r2.id IS NULL

and (machine = record2.machine and record.time_stamp < record2.time_stamp or record.time_stamp = recrod2.time_stamp and record.id < record2.id)
```